# JavaScript: How to group nested array

Tags: javascript, react-native, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to display data using SectionList in React Native. I have written the code below displaying what I am trying to accomplish.

I want the data to first be grouped together by `date`, and inside of that date, I need them grouped by location. A regular JavaScript solution will work. It's important that it has a `title` and `data` key.

My input data is in this format:

```
[ { game_id: 1171,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Plaza'
   },
  { game_id: 1189,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1489,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1488,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Soccer'
   }
]
```

I need the obtain the following output from the data array above:

```
data = [{
    title: "2018-11-17",
    data: [{
            title: "Field - Kickball",
            data: [{
                game_id: 1189,
                date: '2018-11-17',
                location: 'Field - Kickball'
            }]
        },
        {
            title: "Plaza",
            data: [{
                game_id: 1171,
                date: '2018-11-17',
                location: 'Plaza'
            }]
        }
    ]
    },
    {
        title: "2018-11-16",
        data: [{
                title: "Field - Kickball",
                data: [{
                    game_id: 1489,
                    date: '2018-11-16',
                    location: 'Field - Kickball'
                }]
            },
            {
                title: "Field - Soccer",
                data: [{
                    game_id: 1488,
                    date: '2018-11-16',
                    location: 'Field - Soccer'
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried this already:

```
const games = [data here]
var groups = _(games)
.groupBy(x => x.date)
        .map(value => {
            return _.groupBy(value, 'location')
            .map(({key, value}) => ({title: key, data: value}))
        })

        .map((value, key) => {
            return ({title: value[Object.keys(value)[0]][0].date, data: value})
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a standard solution, then you could first reduce to an object, and return the values of that object, and then group again on the output :)

```js
function groupBy( arr, prop ) {
  return Object.values( arr.reduce( ( aggregate, item ) => {
    const val = item[prop];
    if (!aggregate[val]) {
      aggregate[val] = {
        [prop]: val,
        data: []
      };
    }
    aggregate[val].data.push( item );
    return aggregate;
  }, {} ) );
}

const games = [ { game_id: 1171,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Plaza'
   },
  { game_id: 1189,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1489,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1488,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Soccer'
   }
];

const grouped = groupBy( games, 'date' )
  .map( item => ({ ...item, data: groupBy( item.data, 'location' ) }) );
  
console.log( grouped );
```

Note that I just use the prop that got extracted as a target property for the grouping, if you want `title` instead, just change the `[prop]: val` to `'title': val` and then you can make your second grouping a litle bit easier :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways this can be achieved, however a simple approach that does not require third party dependencies like Underscore or Lodash, can implemented with the built-in [Array#reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method as shown below.

Please see the documentation in the following code snippet for details on how this solution works:

```js
const input =  [ { game_id: 1171, date: '2018-11-17', location: 'Plaza' }, { game_id: 1189, date: '2018-11-17', location: 'Field - Kickball' }, { game_id: 1489, date: '2018-11-16', location: 'Field - Kickball' }, { game_id: 1488, date: '2018-11-16', location: 'Field - Soccer' } ];


/* Reduce input data to required nested sub-array structure */
const data = input.reduce((result, item) => {

  /* Construct item to be inserted into sub array for this item.date
  in resulting data object */
  const resultItem = {
    title: item.location,
    data: [{
      game_id: item.game_id,
      date: item.date,
      location: item.location
    }]
  };

  /* Find existing item in result array with title that matches date */
  const resultDateList = result.find(i => i.title === item.date);

  if (resultDateList) {

    /* If matching sublist found, add constructed item to it's data array */
    resultDateList.data.push(resultItem);
  } else {

    /* If not matching sublist found, add a new one to the result for this item
    and pre-populate the data array with new item*/
    result.push({
      title: item.date,
      data: [resultItem]
    });
  }

  return result;

}, [])

console.log(data)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, this is not exacly right, I guess I forgot to include that edge case. There could be multiple games at that time and location, which has to be included. Meaning there can be a game happening on 2019-11-17 at Plaza, but your current setup doesnt include those

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with ES6 and without lodash:

```js
let arr = [ { game_id: 1171, date: '2018-11-17', location: 'Plaza' }, { game_id: 1189, date: '2018-11-17', location: 'Field - Kickball' }, { game_id: 1489, date: '2018-11-16', location: 'Field - Kickball' }, { game_id: 1488, date: '2018-11-16', location: 'Field - Soccer' } ]

let groupByfield = (data, field) => data.reduce((r, c) => {
  let key = c[field]
  r[key] = r[key] || {title: key, data: []}
  r[key].data = [...(r[key].data || []), c] 
  return r
}, {})

let result = Object.values(groupByfield(arr, 'date'))
  .map(x => ({ 
    title: x.title, 
    data: Object.values(groupByfield(x.data, 'location'))
   })
)

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to create your custom `groupBy` function and then use it for your groupings.

We are using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Is there an error here? It seems the nested `data` object is a map (with keys like `Plaza`) rather than an array?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a function using `_.flow()` that can group an array by a field, and convert it to the format of { title, data }. The function should also accept a transformer for the data. Now you can use it recursively to group multiple times.

```js
const { identity, flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map } = _

const groupByKey = (key, transformer = identity) => flow(
  pr(groupBy, key),
  pr(map, (data, title) => ({
    title,
    data: transformer(data)
  }))
)

const data = [{"game_id":1171,"date":"2018-11-17","location":"Plaza"},{"game_id":1189,"date":"2018-11-17","location":"Field - Kickball"},{"game_id":1489,"date":"2018-11-16","location":"Field - Kickball"},{"game_id":1488,"date":"2018-11-16","location":"Field - Soccer"}]

const result = groupByKey('date', groupByKey('location'))(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea with lodash/fp:

```js
const { identity, flow, groupBy, map, get } = _

const groupByKey = (key, transformer = identity) => flow(
  groupBy(key),
  map(data => ({
    title: get([0, key], data),
    data: transformer(data)
  }))
)

const data = [{"game_id":1171,"date":"2018-11-17","location":"Plaza"},{"game_id":1189,"date":"2018-11-17","location":"Field - Kickball"},{"game_id":1489,"date":"2018-11-16","location":"Field - Kickball"},{"game_id":1488,"date":"2018-11-16","location":"Field - Soccer"}]

const result = groupByKey('date', groupByKey('location'))(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```