# JavaScript ES6: array of objects to array grouped by key and indexed by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. The simplified version (with just a few of the properties):

```
let d = [
{ team:"sales", key:"employees", value:24 },
{ team:"sales", key:"floor", value:2 },
{ team:"finance", key:"employees", value:7 },
{ team:"finance", key:"floor", value:2 },
]
```

Want to group by `team` and then by `key`, using plain (ES6) JavaScript:

```
{
  sales: {
    employees: { team:"sales", key:"employees", value:24 },
    floor: { team:"sales", key:"floor", value:2 }
  },
  finance: {
    employees: { team:"finance", key:"employees", value:7 },
    floor: { team:"finance", key:"floor", value:2 }
  }
}
```

Somewhat similar to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212466/javascript-how-to-group-nested-array), but not quite.

What I have so far: using reduce to group by `team`:

```
let groupBy = (data, field) => data.reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, { [obj[field]]:( acc[obj[field]] || [] ).concat(obj) }), {})

let result = groupBy(d,'team')
```

This gives:

```
{
sales: [
  { team:"sales", key:"employees", value:24 },
  { team:"sales", key:"floor", value:2 }
],
finance: [
  { team:"finance", key:"employees", value:7 },
  { team:"finance", key:"floor", value:2 }
]
}
```

Not sure what the recommended way is to group by the `key` level inside the teams.

Comment: Do the same thing again, in a loop, on the individual arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accumulating to an array by concatenating each object to a new array, you can accumulate to a new object literal. You can do this by spreading the accumulated object into a new object literal. Then, again, you can spread the result of the accumulated object for the current objects team or take a default object (`|| {}`) if one doesn't exist. Lastly, you can set a new key on your nested object literal of `obj.key` and sets its value to be the current iterated object itself.

```js
const data = [
  { team:"sales", key:"employees", value:24 },
  { team:"sales", key:"floor", value:2 },
  { team:"finance", key:"employees", value:7 },
  { team:"finance", key:"floor", value:2 },
];

const groupBy = (array, field) => array.reduce((acc, obj) =>
  ({...acc, [obj[field]]: {...(acc[obj[field]] || {}), [obj.key]: obj}}), {});

console.log(groupBy(data,'team'));
```

Comment: thanks for the clean & clear solution *and* good explanation of how it works. I have decided to use your solution, and decided to skip the groupBy function by hardcoding both `team` and `key` properties: `const result = data.reduce((acc, obj) =>
  ({...acc, [obj.team]: {...(acc[obj.team] || {}), [obj.key]: obj}}), {})`

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of keys for grouping and reduce the object by checking and adding new objects or for the last key take the object from the data.

```js
let d = [{ team: "sales", key: "employees", value: 24 }, { team: "sales", key:" floor", value: 2 }, { team: "finance", key: "employees", value: 7 }, { team: "finance", key: "floor", value: 2 }],
    groups = ['team', 'key'],
    result = d.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        groups.reduce((o, key, i, { length }) => {
             const k = obj[key];
             return o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === length ? obj : {});
        }, acc);
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce

```js
let d = [{ team:"sales", key:"employees", value:24 },{ team:"sales", key:"floor", value:2 },{ team:"finance", key:"employees", value:7 },{ team:"finance", key:"floor", value:2 },]

let groupBy = (data, property) => data.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let prop = inp[property]
  let key = inp.key
  op[prop] = op[prop] || {}
  op[prop][key] = op[prop][key] || {}
  op[prop][key] = inp
  return op
}, {})


console.log(groupBy(d, 'team'))
```